# Dojo store duplication in cache

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am using a combination of dojo and [cbtree](https://github.com/pjekel/cbtree) to build a treeview with checkboxes. Because the data is on the server I use a JsonRest store to retrieve it. Because I don't want every action going to the server the JsonRest is combined with a Memory in a Cache.

A simplified example looks like the following:

```
define([
  'dojo/_base/declare',
  'dojo/store/JsonRest', 'dojo/store/Memory', 'dojo/store/Cache',
  'cbtree/model/TreeStoreModel', 'cbtree/Tree'
], function(declare,
  JsonRest, Memory, Cache,
  TreeStoreModel, Tree) {
  return declare(null, {
    buildTree: function() {
      var self = this;
      this._memory = new Memory();
      this._restStore = new JsonRest({
        target: '/process_trees/',
        getSelectedItems: function() {
          var checkedIds = [];
          array.forEach(self._memory.query(), function(item) {
            if(item.checked || item.checked == 'mixed') {
              checkedIds.push(item);
            }
          })

          return checkedIds;
        }
      });
      var cache = Cache(restStore, memory);
      this._treeModel = new TreeStoreModel({
        store: cache
      });
    }
  })
}
```

During the execution of the tree I check some items in the tree and I see in the Cache the put function being called with the new item in which the checked property is set to true and this value is stored in memory.

After a while I want to get all the items that are checked so I call the getSelectedItems function but when I look in the local memory in the function, self._memory, not a single item is checked even though I have checked several items.

Does anybody know why this is happening?